# Post Type Error

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I added a code in my php and i don't know what is wrong, it shows only 2 posts but I got 10 posts in my WordPress can someone check my code?

```
<?php
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_name' => 'appetizers',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
            $Loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php while ( $Loop->have_posts() ) : $Loop->the_post();?>
                <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">                 
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php the_field('price'); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: have you assigned category - "appetizers" to all posts?

Comment: add 'posts_per_page' => -1 in $args. May be it is picking up the number of posts from the 'Setting -> Reading' option in back end.

Comment: yes, i already check it 4 times now.

Comment: happy to help :). I have added this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

add `'posts_per_page' => -1` in $args.

May be it is picking up the number of posts from the 'Setting -> Reading' option in back end.